# How to get data from my Collection as a string?

Tags: javascript, object, meteor, collections, countdown

I wrote a datepicker where a user is able to enter a date inside of an input field with bootstrap:

```
    <template name="date">
      <form>
         <div class="input-group datetimepicker">
           <input name="date" class="set-due-date form-control" type="text"/>
           <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
         </div>
          ...
     </form>
    </template>
```

After this i insert it into my collection with some other information of the form and route the user to a new page.

```
    Template.date.events({
     'submit form':function(event,t){
      event.preventDefault();
      Questions.insert({
      closeDateDB: $('[name="date"]').val(),   
      ...
      ..
      },
    function (error,results){
      Router.go('decision', {_id:results})};
    });
```

There i wanna get the Information of the closeDateDB for my countdown timer and redirect the user when endtime > currentTime.

```
var timeinterval;

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var endtime = *The closeDateDB of the submitted form!;*
    timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
      Meteor.call("getCurrentTime", function (error, result) {
        Session.set("time", result);
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
        Session.set("t", t);
      });
    }, 1000);
  });

  function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
    var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Session.get('time');
    var seconds = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 )).slice(-2);
    var minutes = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 )).slice(-2);
    var hours = ("0" + Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 )).slice(-2);
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );


    if(t <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timeinterval);
      Router.go('finalpage');
   }
    return {
      'total': t,
      'days': days,
      'hours': hours,
      'minutes': minutes,
      'seconds': seconds
    };

  }

  Template.countdown.helpers({
    t: function () {
      return Session.get("t");
    }
  });

  Template.body.helpers({
    ended:function () {
      console.log(Session.get("t").total <= 0);
      return Session.get("t").total <= 0;
    }
  });


Template.date.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      locale: 'en',
      format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
    });
});
```

Could anyone help me how i get the inserted closeDateDB as a string for my countdown?? I am new to Meteor and i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't totally understand your question, but it seems like the core of it is "redirect the user when endtime > currentTime". If the difference between `endtime` and `currentTime` is seconds rather than minutes, you may be able to use `setTimeout`. Otherwise, you should do something with a cron job that flags the `Question` as "ready" at `endTime` or something along those lines. Again, the problem isn't clear and some broader information about what you're trying to achieve would help.

Comment: The first step is submitting a form with some informations like the `closeDateDB` which should be the endtime for my counter. Then the user will be redirected to a new page with router.go. There will be a decision page where user can write some comments to a specific question for the amount of currentTime > endtime. When the time is over this page should be closed and another router.go should redirect him to a result page.
But i dont know how to get the `closeDateDB` from my collection and set it to the `endtime`. I tried something like `Question.findOne();` but didnt know how to get a string

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to make sure that you save `closeDateDB` in a time format so that you can directly compare it to current time, i.e. `if ( closeDateDB > new Date() )` will not work if `closeDateDB` is a string.
2. You're doing your countdown in a very complicated way. Use the [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package to make time itself *reactive* and save yourself most of that code

Comment: But how can i get closeDateDB in a time format? At the moment i just get it as a `$('[name="date"]').val()`. This saves a string in my database

Comment: The calendar control is probably going to give you a specific string format, for example `yyyy/MM/dd`. Parse that and make `var d = new Date(yyyy,MM,dd)`. IMO it's better to do this on save than to have to parse the data on read every single time afterwards. Plus it will let you perform date queries against MongoDB that you'll never be able to do with strings.

Comment: It looks like you're using bootstrap datetimepicker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which uses momentjs. So you can parse a Date object from the input's string value like this: `moment($('[name="date"]').val(), 'MM/DD/YYYY').toDate();`. Then save it to your collection and you'll be able to do your date comparison.

Comment: Yes you are right i am using bootstrap-datetimepicker. I tried it and i get now a Date object from the input's string value. But how do i get it for my `var endtime` ?

Comment: Isn't your `endtime` originally `closeDateDB` which is now of type date?

Comment: If i try to get endtime with `var endtime = Questions.findOne({_id:this._id}).closeDateDB;` nothing happens and i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closeDateDB' of undefined`

Comment: That just means there is no question with `_id:this._id` - are you sure your data context is what you expect it to be?

Comment: but even if i enter a specific id var endtime = Questions.findOne({_id:"FsueYKDw2NfsrX96w"}).closeDateDB; i am able to get the value if i type this in my console. But how to get the id of the _id i created before in my form

Comment: Did you store this `_id` anywhere?

Comment: if i submit the form and i wanna do something like: Qustions.insert({myId:this._id}); it doesnt get the _id...

Comment: You can do `_id = Questions.insert(object);` and get the `_id` right away.

Comment: do u mean something like :   `var _id = Questions.insert({ closeDateDB: $('[name="date"]').val(),   
      ...
    newId= 0,}); Questions.update({newId = _id});`??

Comment: `Questions.update({ _id = _id});` Remember that mongo is going to give you a document `_id` automatically, it's the key by which you perform updates and deletes (although you can also search on other fields of course but `_id` is indexed and unique.